# File deleted from App Bundle in Xcode still readable

Tags: ios, xcode, nsbundle

I have a bunch of Audio Files in my App Bundle, I was reading using

```
 [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:aaa ofType:m4a]
```

I found that even if I delete the aaa.m4a by moving to trash my app is can read and play the audio file (using AVAudioPlayer). I checked by search in the Xcode project's directory, that it doesn't exist. I checked also from Build Phrases - Copy Bundle Resources, that aaa.m4a is not there.

Anybody has any ideas why?

Comment: Whenever you change or remove your resources please clean the project and delete the app from the device

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File is kept somewhere during build & run process.

- In Xcode Go to Organizer > Projects > Your project > Remove Derived Data
- On your device Delete app

Run on device and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

**If you are running on device, Please delete the app and run again.**

If you are running on simulator, please try the below four steps.

1. Delete the **aaa.m4a** item from your Trash. It may still have reference to the original location to restore it again.
2. Open you simulator, go to `iOS Simulator menu-->Select 'Reset Content and Settings'-->click 'Reset'`.
3. Open Xcode, then go to `Organizer-->Projects-->MyProject-->Delete All derived data` folders.

Comment: go to your  /Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications and delete it.

Comment: I was running on device, not simulator, but I'll try to delete the folder and let you know, thanks

Comment: If you are running on device, Please delete the app and run again.

Comment: Need to completely remove the app + Remove Derived Data, both actions together. Thank you

Comment: note that 3. (reset) includes 2. (delete all apps manually) so 2. unecessary I think